# How to dynamically change the state of a child class from a parent class? React Native

Tags: react-native

So, this is the **parent class**:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        pickedTxtMsgType: enums.TxtMsgType.CONFIRM_PHONE_NUMBER

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.parentView}>

        <View style={styles.view3}>
            <TxtMsgParamView
                onChangeText = {(text) => this.setState({text: text})}
                txtMsgType = {this.state.pickedTxtMsgType}
            >   
            </TxtMsgParamView>
        </View>



        <View style={styles.view4}>
            <TxtMsgTypePicker
                onValueChange = {(pickedTxtMsgType) => this.setState({pickedTxtMsgType: pickedTxtMsgType})}
            >
            </TxtMsgTypePicker>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When the TxtMsgTypePicker class chooses a value, it sets the **state.pickedTxtMsgType**. And throughout the application, this class can pick multiple values. And I want the selection from the TxtMsgTypePicker class to be passed down to a child class and set a state from a child class. And this is the child class:

```
export class TxtMsgParamView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      txtMsgType: this.props.txtMsgType
    }
    this.visibilityManager = new VisibilityManager()
    this.txtMsgCreator = new TxtMsgCreator()

  }

  onChangeText(text, txtMsgParamType) {
    this.txtMsgCreator.setTxtMsgParamValue(text, txtMsgParamType)
    var txtMsg = this.txtMsgCreator.createTxtMsg(this.state.txtMsgType)
    this.props.onChangeText(this.state.txtMsgType)
  }
}
```

However, the problem is, in the child class, the txtMsgType remains **enums.TxtMsgType.CONFIRM_PHONE_NUMBER** even if the TxtMsgTypePicker class picks a different value. So, the child class only has the initial value set by the TxtMsgTypePicker class. And it is not allowing the TxtMsgTypePicker class to set a different value for the txtMsgType in the child class.

Thank you for your help ahead of time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`?

It would look something like this:

```
export class TxtMsgParamView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      txtMsgType: this.props.txtMsgType
    }
    this.visibilityManager = new VisibilityManager()
    this.txtMsgCreator = new TxtMsgCreator()

  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.txtMsgType !== nextProps.txtMsgType) {
      this.setState({txtMsgType: nextProps.txtMsgType})
    }
  }

  onChangeText(text, txtMsgParamType) {
    this.txtMsgCreator.setTxtMsgParamValue(text, txtMsgParamType)
    var txtMsg = this.txtMsgCreator.createTxtMsg(this.state.txtMsgType)
    this.props.onChangeText(this.state.txtMsgType)
  }
}
```

Although componentWillReceiveProps is considered UNSAFE by latest React, it has proven useful in cases like this. Also in case that `componentWillReceiveProps` cannot be found by your Component, try `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps`. If you'd like to read more, here you go: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

EDIT: The answer above is considered UNSAFE for a good reason. It leads to anti-patterns that, although can be avoided, often times occur by accident.

### getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)

With the slow deprecation of `componentWillReceiveProps`, the React team introduced [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#new-lifecycle-getderivedstatefromprops), that performs the job of `componentWillReceiveProps` in a safer manner.

In this lifecycle method, you should return an object with the fields of the state that you would like to be modified based on the props, or `null` if the new props do not require a change of state.

Using your use-case as an example, you would have to change:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.txtMsgType !== nextProps.txtMsgType) {
      this.setState({txtMsgType: nextProps.txtMsgType})
    }
  }
```

to:

```
  getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.txtMsgType !== state.txtMsgType) {
      return ({txtMsgType: props.txtMsgType})
    }
  }
```

However, even [this approach has its drawbacks.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

### Single source of truth

In your example usage, when `TxtMsgParamView` mounts, the parent (`App`) provides it with the data that will be displayed. This is the `true` data. However, once the component is mounted and the user makes changes to the `TxtMsgParamView`, it is the child (`TxtMsgParamView`) that maintains that data on its state, so the `source of truth` changed from the parent to the child. The fact that the parent can override the `state` of the child but not know at all times what that `state` is, [leads to bugs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#common-bugs-when-using-derived-state).

For that reason, you should highly consider moving the data to a single source of truth. As mentioned in the **Common Bugs When Using Derived State** section of the last article linked, "controlled" and "uncontrolled" mean the following:

> The terms “controlled” and “uncontrolled” usually refer to form inputs, but they can also describe where any component’s data lives. Data passed in as props can be thought of as controlled (because the parent component controls that data). Data that exists only in internal state can be thought of as uncontrolled (because the parent can’t directly change it).

The best idea, in my opinion, would be to pick which one fits best your needs, and stick to it.

### Controlled Component

For your example, and since `TxtMsgTypePicker`, the sibling of `TxtMsgParamView`, can modify the parent's `state` and therefore also modify `TxtMsgParamView`'s `state`, I would suggest using a controlled component.

This means that `App` will fully control what `TxtMsgParamView` renders, making `TxtMsgParamView` a stateless component:

App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        text: '',
        pickedTxtMsgType: enums.TxtMsgType.CONFIRM_PHONE_NUMBER
    }
  }

    this.onTxtMsgChange = (text, txtMsgParamType) => {
        this.txtMsgCreator.setTxtMsgParamValue(text, txtMsgParamType)
        var txtMsg = this.txtMsgCreator.createTxtMsg(this.state.txtMsgType)
        this.setState({pickedTxtMsgType: txtMsg})
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.parentView}>

        <View style={styles.view3}>
            <TxtMsgParamView
                onChangeText = {this.onTxtMsgChange}
                txtMsgType = {this.state.pickedTxtMsgType}
            >   
            </TxtMsgParamView>
        </View>



        <View style={styles.view4}>
            <TxtMsgTypePicker
                onValueChange = {(pickedTxtMsgType) => this.setState({pickedTxtMsgType: pickedTxtMsgType})}
            >
            </TxtMsgTypePicker>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

TxtMsgParamView.js

```
export class TxtMsgParamView extends React.Component {

  onChangeText(text, txtMsgParamType) {
    this.props.onChangeText(text, txtMsgParamType)
  }

  render() {
    const {txtMsgParamType} = this.props
    return <TextInput value={txtMsgParamType} onChangeText={this.onChangeText} />
  }
}
```

While I do not know the whole code for your use-case, what is important to note in my example code is that `TxtMsgParamView` has no state, and it lets the parent, `App.js` handle a change in text. Essentially, `onTxtMsgChange` is a dumb component and simply renders the data it is sent as props, and calls functions sent by the parent when needed. it does not modify the data in any way by itself.

Like this, now `App` is the single source of truth, and you have saved yourself some debugging hours to find a bug on `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One question. Is there a workaround to this solution where it won't cause bugs and be depecrated in the future? Let me know!

Comment: @aejhyun I have updated my answer with examples and links to blog posts that might help you better understand the reason behind the deprecation of `componentWillUpdate`.